# Having trouble when passing string with bundle from MainActivity to Fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im having trouble when passing a test string from **MainActivity** to **TabFragment_malica1**. I get *"Attempt to invoke virtual method .. on a null object"* error. I can see that bundle is a null object with an *if statement*, but i cannot figure out what did i do wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  String varTest = new String();
  String[] testArray = new String[3];

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab1));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);



    sendData();

    public void sendData() {

      varTest = "TEST-TEST-TEST";


      //PACKING DATA IN A BUNDLE
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("TEST", varTest);


      //PASSING DATA OVER THE BUNDLE TO FRAGMENT
      TabFragment_malica1 myFragment = new TabFragment_malica1();
      myFragment.setArguments(bundle);


      //TEST BUNDLE
      Log.d("MAIN FRAGMENT DATA:", String.valueOf(bundle));

    }
  }
```

FRAGMENT

```
public class TabFragment_malica1 extends Fragment {

  public TabFragment_malica1() {

  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
      String text = bundle.getString("TEST");
      Log.d("TEST LOG", text);
    } else {
      Log.d("ERROR", "ERROR!");
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_malica1, container, false);

  }
}
```

Comment: For communicating between activity and fragment, Interface will be more useful

Comment: How you are launching the Fragment? I see no fragment transaction here.

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria, I did not quite understand you as well. I see he is using a `PagerAdapter`. However, he has not added the fragments into the `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: Can you show the body of the PagerAdapter please.